# threshold on the number of allowed mapped pages per process

Tags: c

The thing I'm trying to achieve here is to make large number of small (page size) `mmap()` calls and check `/proc/slabinfo` each time until only one slab is left. But during the execution of my code, I `cat /proc/slabinfo` to see the number of available `vm_area_struct` but it does not go down. I guess there is a threshold on the number of allowed mapped pages per process, right?

```
#define BASE (char *) 0x60000000

char *swapmem = NULL;
char *base = BASE;
char *map_addr;
static volatile int map_flags = PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ;
static char name[128];
static char line[128];

int get_slab_objs(const char *sn)
{
static int c, d, u = 0, a = 0;
FILE *fp=NULL;
char x1[20];

    fp = fopen("/proc/slabinfo", "r");
    if(!fp)
        printf("%s\n", "Not able to open /proc/slabinfo");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name) - 1, fp);
    do {
        c = u = a = -1;
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof(line) - 1, fp))
            break;
        c = sscanf(line, "%s %u %u %u %u %u %u", name, &u, &a,
               &d, &d, &d, &d);
    } while (strcmp(name, sn));
    close(fileno(fp));
    fclose(fp);
    return c == 7 ? a - u : -1;
}

//  leave one object in the SLAB
inline void prepare_slab()
{
void *r;

    r = mmap(map_addr, PAGE_SIZE, map_flags,
                 MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_FIXED, 0, 0);

    map_addr += PAGE_SIZE;
    map_flags ^= PROT_READ;     

    if(MAP_FAILED == r) {
        printf("--> prepare_slab() failed\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    map_addr = swapmem + 16*PAGE_SIZE + MEMSZ;

    int r;
    r = get_slab_objs("vm_area_struct");  
    while(r != 1 && r > 0) 
    {   
        prepare_slab();   
        r--;  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though you're trying to run [this old `uselib()` exploit](https://lwn.net/Articles/118955/).

It's not going to work on any modern system. The vulnerability used by this exploit was patched ten years ago, and the `uselib()` system call isn't even present in some newer kernels. Additionally, the `/proc/slabinfo` proc entry is only readable by root nowadays, so this code won't run unless you already have root access.